# Disable focusable event for divider and list items on ListViewAdapter on Android

Tags: android, focus, android-listview, listviewitem

I created a list view based on:
http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

This is a custom list view that allows insert custom header/divider on custom list adapter.
I'm also using style.xml for list view and .xml files for list item and list item header that can be added to the custom list view.

One problem:
I can't seem to control the focus for the listed items.
I want to disable focusable events for ALL listed items (i.e. avoid listed item to have that glaring orange highlight when focused on scroll events).

I already checked the focus demos on ApiDemos project found in android SDK to no avail 
(setting focusable=false to either create view instance on activity OR .xml).

Are there any other ways to disable the focus for listed items?

Answer (score 0):

By using Selector you can change or remove the focus color of list items .

here is a link for this..http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html